# How to disable / enable an input field with a checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox, input

Current code:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group" id="deadline" >
    <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" id="deadline" name="deadline" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" >
    <input type="checkbox" value="ongoing" name="Ongoing" id="ongoing" >
    <label for="ongoing">Ongoing</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

how do i make it so that checking the "Ongoing" checkbox disables the "deadline" input field?
Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Your best bet is to use javascript

Comment: could you give an example of how i would go about doing that?

Comment: @JakeB checked my answer, it is with JS and you used `deadline` for div as `id`which caused the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery would be easiest way in my opinion

```
$('#ongoing').change(function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    $('#deadline').prop('disabled',true);
  } else {
    $('#deadline').prop('disabled',false);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not tagged with jQuery.

Comment: The author seems to be searching for a solution. Plain HTML is not a solution. You shouldn't down vote just for that.

Comment: I have agreed to that and removed the downvote. `:)`

Comment: Regardless of what my tags were, it's not possible otherwise. Thjs was a quick and simple solution to the issue in the  fewest lines possible, thanks

Comment: @JakeB Great. Check out my answer below for better and short code of this version. Upto you to take the best... `:)`

Answer (score 1):

please use jQuery or javascript

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group" id="deadline" >
    <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" id="deadline" name="deadline" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" >
    <input type="checkbox" value="ongoing" name="Ongoing" id="ongoing" >
    <label for="ongoing">Ongoing</label>
  </div>
</form>


<script>
 $("#ongoing).change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')
   {
     $('#deadline').attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
    else{
                  $('#deadline').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
 });
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery for this...Your code will be as follow-

```
 $('#ongoing').change(function() {
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('#deadline').prop('disabled',false);
            }
          else
    {  $('#deadline').prop('disabled',true);} 
        });
```

Comment: This is not tagged with jQuery.

Comment: yeah so using jqury or javasript is the only option.. dont just downvote beace the question isnt tagged with jquery..it is also not tagged wiht javascript...i dont understand your thinking

Comment: @PraveenKumar your argument is baseless

Comment: Yea, agreed mate.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onclick` event and call a function like this: and remove id of this div `<div class="form-group" id="deadline" >` since you are using the same id for field.

```
<html>


<script>
var disabled=0;
function disableEnableField(){

    if(disabled==0){ //disable
     document.getElementById('deadline').disabled = true;
       disabled=1; 
     } 
    else{  //enable again
     document.getElementById('deadline').disabled = false;
      disabled=0; 
    } 
}
</script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group" >
    <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control"  id="deadline" name="deadline" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" >
    <input type="checkbox" value="ongoing" onclick="disableEnableField()" name="Ongoing" id="ongoing" >
    <label  >Ongoing</label>
  </div>
</form>


</html>
```

Comment: Mate, I tried this. But is this really working? Coz I couldn't make it working. See my answer if you can see it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it is working... check my updated answer..it didn't work previously because of repeated id

Answer (score 0):

The more better and quicker solution than the one provided is:

```
$('#ongoing').change(function() {
  $('#deadline').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove or rename that form-control div to some other name.The same id name for input tag and div is conflicting and the code is looking for the first one .Thats why here no codes working.I edited accordingly.Kindly go through it.include jquery .Its important.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>


<script>
$(function () {
        $("input[name='Ongoing']").click(function () {
            if ($("#ongoing").is(":checked")) {
                $("#deadline").removeAttr("disabled");
                
              
                
            } else {
                $("#deadline").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                
                 
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
```

i edited your code as required.

```
<body>
<form>
  <div class="form-group" id="deadlinediv" >
    <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" id="deadline" name="deadline" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="checkbox" value="ongoing" name="Ongoing" id="ongoing" >
    <label for="ongoing">Ongoing</label>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So many other ways already explained .May be this too will help somebody.